# CSS bring img to front

Tags: html, css, position

Im having some trouble getting an image back to the front.

So basically this is my code segment:

```
<itemimg>
    <a href="images/table1.jpg" data-lightbox="table1" data-title="Rustic Green Table"><img src="images/table1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/table1-side.jpg" data-lightbox="table1" data-title="Rustic Green Table"><img src="images/table1-side.jpg"></a>
</itemimg>
```

The second `a href` which links `table1-side.jpg is overlapping the`table1.jpg`but i want it the other way around.`table1.jpg` should be on top.

The css that affects this part is here:

```
itemimg {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
itemimg img:nth-child(1) {
z-index: 9999;
}
itemimg img:nth-child(2) {
z-index: 0;
}
itemimg img {
position: absolute;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
itemimg a {
display: block;
position: absolute;
cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

I tried (as you can see), to send the second image to the back with `z-index` but it isnt doing it. I even tried messing with the `position` property on the `itemimg img` to see if it will re-arrange them. I even switched them around in the HTML so one is on top and it *does* work **BUT** i am using Lightbox and when i arrange the HTML to where the `table1.jpg` is on top, the navigation in Lightbox is backwards (as in i have to press the left arrow to go backwards instead of forwards to see the images). <- i know this might be confusing but take a look at it for yourself [here](http://rusticrentals.oldtreasuresfurniture.com/rentals/bars.html). Click on the table to bring up Lightbox and you have to navigate backwards in the slideshow NOT forwards, which is what i dont want. So i figured if i can get the `table1.jpg`
 on top, it will go forwards as i want it to and thats what im having trouble with.

Really need help here, Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**

For people who wanted to know the solution. Depending on your scenario the below answers work great. I, however wanted to avoid using inline css and classes so i implemented my images into an `ul` and set the 2nd `li`'s `z-index` to `-1` as such:

**HTML**

```
<itemimg>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="images/table1.jpg" data-lightbox="table1" data-title="Rustic Green Table"><img src="images/table1.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/table1-side.jpg" data-lightbox="table1" data-title="Rustic Green Table"><img src="images/table1-side.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</itemimg>
```

**CSS**

```
itemimg {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
itemimg ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
itemimg li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}
itemimg ul li:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: -1;
}
itemimg img {
    position: absolute;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
itemimg a {
    display: block;
    position: inherit;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

My website is updated with the end result so [go and take a look!](http://rusticrentals.oldtreasuresfurniture.com/rentals/bars.html)

Comment: Your "itemimg img:nth-child(2)" is not being applied to anything. Both images are getting z-index: 9999;

Using Google's developer's tools I went in and added style="z-index:-1;" to table1-side.jpg and it worked. How you want to implement this is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies on the 2nd z-index. Make it -1 like this:

```
itemimg {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
itemimg img:nth-child(1) {
z-index: 9999;
}
itemimg img:nth-child(2) {
z-index: -1; //make this -1
}
itemimg img {
position: absolute;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
itemimg a {
display: block;
position: absolute;
cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up implementing the images into an `ul` and used your method but on the 2nd `li` and it worked great! I completely forgot about -1 on `z-index` so thanks for reminding me!

Comment: You're welcome! I forget stuff all the time *^^ I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The z-index for both images is 9999.

Solution 1:

Hard code one of them in the HTML.

```
<itemimg>
<a href="images/table1.jpg" data-lightbox="table1" data-title="Rustic Green Table"><img src="images/table1.jpg" style="z-index:10000"/></a>
<a href="images/table1-side.jpg" data-lightbox="table1" data-title="Rustic Green Table"><img src="images/table1-side.jpg"></a>
```

Solution 2:

Give the front image a id and name it something like "frontImage" then add

```
.frontImage {
    z-index:10000;
}
```